# how to allow only -Ve or +Ve values in text box using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to allow the user input to be only 
`-Ve or +Ve`

using java script.

I have tried something as follows but it is not allowing any value in the text box to be entered.

```
function rhFactor(txtBoxObj)
{  
   var pve = "+ve";
   var nve = "-ve";
    var ve = false;
    if( validTxtBoxObj(txtBoxObj))
    {
        if(pve == txtBoxObj.value || nve == txtBoxObj.value )
        {
            ve = true;
        }

        if(ve == false)
        {
           // alert('Allowed RH Factors - +ve,-ve');
            txtBoxObj.value="";
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is how i called

```
onkeyup="rhFactor(this)"
```

UPDATE :

```
function validTxtBoxObj(txtBoxObj)
{
    if(txtBoxObj != null) return true;
    return false
}
```

Please help me to get this work.

Comment: What does `validTxtBoxObj` do?

Comment: Don't use `onkeyup`. You won't be able to type the whole value. Use `onchange` or `oninput` instead.

Comment: keyup fires for *every* key so as soon as the first - or + is entered you test it against something it can never be, why not limit the test to cases when the value is >= 3 characters or use a more appropriate event. (Or use a <select>)

Comment: @Anto: For readabilty and conciseness, you should get rid of the `ve` variable and the `validTxtBoxObj` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if( validTxtBoxObj(txtBoxObj))
    {
        hasve = txtBoxObj.value.indexOf(pve) != -1 || txtBoxObj.value.indexOf(nve) != -1;
        if(hasve && parseInt(txtBoxObj.value.replace(pve,'').replace(nve,''),10)+'' != 'NaN' )
        {
            ve = true;
        } else {
           // alert('Allowed RH Factors - +ve,-ve');
            txtBoxObj.value="";
           ve = false;
        }
        return ve;
    }
```

But as pointed out by Bergi you have to run the above validation when user has finished typing, like on submit or click events.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, you *allow only -Ve or +Ve values in text box*. This does not include values like `+` or `+V`, which you would need while typing (and you hook on `keyup`). Pasting a whole value (`Ctrl+V`) should work.

Instead, check the validity on the `change` event - when the user finished his input and turns to the next element.

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ncW74/2/)

Comment: tried what you have explained but it is not working, Ctrl+V, I have followed the 'onkeyup' it is working for other validation it allows only desired value not others.